# Using URL as HTML <img src />

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use a URL which just contains an image to use the image on my site. I am using PHP, this is my code:

```
Echo '<img src= "$link["Image_Link"]"  />';`
```

`$link["Image_Link"]` points to [this link](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5rZrblDyRoTRfDD6RhUfA-_R3hR3cwuJI7A4ew8eoAf1q7toaUYbgoNI1NGJbXCf6BNwGuvho6hPILe8CX4HS427KfH3E/62fx62f).

I also have many similar links which contain different images, and are called like this one. When I call this on my site I just get a broken image symbol where the real image should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single and double quotes are not interchangable in PHP.

This should work:

```
Echo "<img src='$link[Image_Link]' />";
```

or

```
Echo '<img src="' . $link["Image_Link"] . '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) your variable with your string:

```
Echo '<img src= "'.$link["Image_Link"].'"  />';
```

Without it your HTML code in final result will look like:

```
<img src="$link[" Image_Link"]"  />
```

And this is invalid HTML.

Comment: you don't have to concatenate, you can just `echo` multiple parts